# "Total In-/Out- coming connection awareness" - script?

Tags: linux, bash, networking, perl, monitoring

once I had found a bash (or Perl maybe; it's so long ago, that I wasn't knowledgeable about bash enough to tell one set of hieroglyphs from another set so to speak) script that filtered the open files with network connections from `lsof` or `ps -aux` command I think and it updated it regularily with resolution of domain names. It was really nice to have such a good overview of open connections, opening connections, closing connections. I had copied it by the blog of someone, but I doubt he has written it himself and had himself just copied it and was only circulating it, as it was published under some public no-commercial license.

Have you maybe come accross this script or would you know an Ansatz to write something similar in Bash?

Yours sincerely
von Spotz

Comment: Check `iptraf-ng`.

Answer (score 1):

This might meet your needs:

```
#!/bin/sh

BASE=`basename "${0}" ".sh" `
TMP="/tmp/tmp.$$.${BASE}"

sudo lsof -Pni | grep '(ESTABLISHED)' >"${TMP}.connections"
#COMMAND     PID            USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
#firefox    2713      username   88u  IPv4 445702      0t0  TCP 192.168.0.10:42564->142.251.41.4:443 (ESTABLISHED)
#firefox    2713      username   94u  IPv4 445943      0t0  TCP 192.168.0.10:50416->108.138.106.67:443 (ESTABLISHED)
#firefox    2713      username  119u  IPv4  44675      0t0  TCP 192.168.0.10:49430->104.16.249.249:443 (ESTABLISHED)
#firefox    2713      username  158u  IPv4 285032      0t0  TCP 192.168.0.10:57148->198.252.206.25:443 (ESTABLISHED)
#firefox    2713      username  256u  IPv4 446322      0t0  TCP 192.168.0.10:53810->20.127.253.7:443 (ESTABLISHED)"

sudo lsof -Pi | grep '(ESTABLISHED)' >"${TMP}.connections"
#COMMAND     PID            USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
#firefox   2317      username   80u  IPv4  41156      0t0  TCP 192.168.0.10:37300->ec2-44-228-207-167.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:443 (ESTABLISHED)
#firefox   2317      username   82u  IPv4 244978      0t0  TCP 192.168.0.10:50412->239.237.117.34.bc.googleusercontent.com:443 (ESTABLISHED)
#firefox   2317      username  128u  IPv4 173831      0t0  TCP 192.168.0.10:42774->stackoverflow.com:443 (ESTABLISHED)
#firefox   2317      username  129u  IPv4  41121      0t0  TCP 192.168.0.10:47274->104.16.248.249:443 (ESTABLISHED)
#firefox   2317      username  136u  IPv4  48202      0t0  TCP 192.168.0.10:35086->stackoverflow.com:443 (ESTABLISHED)


cat "${TMP}.connections" |
awk '{
    #printf("/proc/%s/fd/1|%s|%s|%s\n", $2, $4, $9, $10 ) ;
    printf("/proc/%s/mountinfo|%s|%s|%s\n", $2, $4, $9, $10 ) ;
}' |
while [ true ]
do
    read line
    if [ -z "${line}" ] ; then exit 0 ; fi

    procpath=`echo "${line}" | awk -F \| '{ print $1 }' `
          fd=`echo "${line}" | awk -F \| '{ print $2 }' `
        conn=`echo "${line}" | awk -F \| '{ print $3 }' `
      status=`echo "${line}" | awk -F \| '{ print $4 }' `

    age=`stat "${procpath}" | grep '^Change' | awk '{ p=index( $3, "." ) ; time=substr( $3, 1, p-1 ) ; print $2, time ; }' `

    dat=`awk -v FD="${fd}" '{ if( $4 == FD ){ print $0 ; exit } ; }' "${TMP}.connections" `

    echo "${age}  ${dat}"
done
```

Output looks like this:

```
2022-09-22 23:06:32  firefox   2317      username   80u  IPv4  41156      0t0  TCP 192.168.0.10:37300->ec2-44-228-207-167.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:443 (ESTABLISHED)
2022-09-22 23:06:32  firefox   2317      username   82u  IPv4 244978      0t0  TCP 192.168.0.10:50412->239.237.117.34.bc.googleusercontent.com:443 (ESTABLISHED)
2022-09-22 23:06:32  firefox   2317      username  128u  IPv4 173831      0t0  TCP 192.168.0.10:42774->stackoverflow.com:443 (ESTABLISHED)
2022-09-22 23:06:32  firefox   2317      username  129u  IPv4  41121      0t0  TCP 192.168.0.10:47274->104.16.248.249:443 (ESTABLISHED)
2022-09-22 23:06:32  firefox   2317      username  136u  IPv4  48202      0t0  TCP 192.168.0.10:35086->stackoverflow.com:443 (ESTABLISHED)
```

That focuses on open connections because those are the one that are actively interacting with the system.